# Magento 2 - Save Extension Attribute afterSave() returns void

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I've been looking into extension attributes from various articles and tutorials:

https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Easy to explain, but the one thing that came up for me is adding an extension attribute to the `CartInterface` model. Basically, if I want to add a plugin for the `save()` repository model it does not return anything `(void)`. How would I go about retrieving the recently saved Quote/Cart going by the above two methods. Right now I just have a method that puts data into the extension attribute, but the data is not persistent elsewhere.

```
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

    // Extension Attributes
    $quoteExtension = $quote->getExtensionAttributes();
    $quoteExtension->setFromApp(true);

    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

Comment: Where the new data are saved in DB?  It have its own model (new table) or the data are saved in the same table "quote"? After I know this, I will can help you better. Here https://www.interactiv4.com/e-commerce-en/extension-attributes-codehacks-i4/?lang=en you can see a explication about this.

Comment: @raumatbel This will be saved in the quote table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First time, you must create a file extension_attributes.xml

> Vendor\Namespace\etc\extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface">
    <attribute code="from_app" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

Then, you have to change the behavior of the **get()**, **getList()** and **save()** function of the repository.

> Vendor\Namespace\etc\extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="vendor_namespace_plugin_cart_repository" type="Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\CartRepositoryPlugin"/>
</type>
```

Having the field in the table of DB **quote**, you can directly save the data by the magic method. If you do this, in the plugin of below, you do not need the function **beforSave().**

```
$quote->setFromApp(true);
$this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

You can do on this way also, in which, the function **beforeSave()** of the plugin of below is mandatory.

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

// Extension Attributes
$quoteExtension = $quote->getExtensionAttributes();
$quoteExtension->setFromApp(true);
$quote->setExtensionAttributes($quoteExtension);

$this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

> Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\CartRepositoryPlugin

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartExtension;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartSearchResultsInterface;

/**
 * Class CartRepositoryPlugin
 */
class CartRepositoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var CartExtensionFactory
     */
    private $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * CartRepositoryPlugin constructor.
     *
     * @param CartExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CartExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->extensionFactory = $orderExtensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param CartInterface $resultEntity
     * @return CartInterface
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGet(
        CartRepositoryInterface $subject,
        CartInterface $resultEntity
    ) {
        /** @var CartExtension $extensionAttributes */
        $extensionAttributes = $resultEntity->getExtensionAttributes() ?: $this->extensionFactory->create();

        $extensionAttributes->setFromApp($resultEntity->getData('from_app'));

        $resultEntity->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $resultEntity;
    }

    /**
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param CartSearchResultsInterface $resultCart
     * @return CartSearchResultsInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(
        CartRepositoryInterface $subject,
        CartSearchResultsInterface $resultCart
    ) {
        /** @var CartInterface $order */
        foreach ($resultCart->getItems() as $order) {
            $this->afterGet($subject, $order);
        }

        return $resultCart;
    }

    /**
     * @param CartRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param CartInterface $result
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeSave(
        CartRepositoryInterface $subject,
        CartInterface $quote
    ) {
        $extensionAttributes = $quote->getExtensionAttributes() ?: $this->extensionFactory->create();
        if ($extensionAttributes !== null && $extensionAttributes->getFromApp() !== null) {
            $quote->setFromApp($extensionAttributes->getFromApp());
        }

        return [$quote];
    }
}
```

How you can look, the function **beforeSave()** use the magic method **setFromApp()** to save the data, instead of this, you can use the magic method directly to save the quote how I explained before.

If the data were in another table of DB with its own model, the function of the plugin will be **afterSave()** and it will seem similar to this.

```
/**
 * @param CartRepositoryInterface $subject
 * @param CartInterface $result
 * @return CartInterface
 */
public function afterSave(
    CartRepositoryInterface $subject,
    CartInterface $result
) {
    $extensionAttributes = $result->getExtensionAttributes() ?: $this->storeExtensionFactory->create();
    if ($extensionAttributes !== null && $extensionAttributes->getFromApp() !== null) {
        /** @var CustomEntity $customEntity */
        $customEntity = $this->customEntityFactory->create();
        $customEntity->setQuoteId($result->getId());
        $customEntity->setFromApp($result->getFromApp());
        $this->customEntityRepository->save($customEntity);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I did not knew I could use magic functions if I had columns made in the appropriate db tables. A far better solution than using extension attributes as I was having issues (unrelated to the question) using them with this project.

Comment: The correct way is use the extension attributes, but if you save the data in the table "quote", for saving you can use the magic method, but you need do the plugin to load the data with the function get() and getList().

Comment: Yeah I get that, but in my current situation I can not use the get() and getList() for reasons unrelated to this question.

Comment: @raumatbel, I have one doubt in the extension attribute. Where the custom created extension attribute was saved in the database.

Comment: @Ramya in my example, you have 2 options: 

1) This is the easiest way. You can create a new field in the quote table and follow the steps of my comment of Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\CartRepositoryPlugin.

2) The other option is to create a table of your own, with your models, resources model ... and as I indicated in the last part of my comment with the afterSave.

Comment: What are the options

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my comment. Can you check it? If you want you can look my post here: https://www.interactiv4.com/e-commerce-en/extension-attributes-codehacks-i4/?lang=en

Comment: That foreach loop in getList() could cause a insanely huge performance gap; there's need to be another way :thinking:

Comment: @raumatbel Hey what if I want to update the shipping total on e.g if shipping amount is 12 while on checkout I want to add some more amount there like 12+5 = 17 how to make shipping amount 17 I've tried that setShippingPrice etc but still it is returning the old price overrided file `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement`